# Separate string value to different variables

Tags: php, regex

I am pulling a string via the Youtube API that gives how long a video is, the string can have different values such as:

```
$time = "PT1H50M20S"; (Video is 1h 50m 20s long)
$time = "PT6M14S"; (Video is 6m 14s long)
$time = "PT11S"; (Video is 11s long)
```

How do I save the hours, minutes and seconds in separate variables? The above code should give:

```
$time = "PT1H50M20S"; -> $h = 5, $m = 50, $s = 20
$time = "PT6M14S"; -> $h = 0, $m = 6, $s = 14
$time = "PT11S"; -> $h = 0, $m = 0, $s = 11
```

Comment: @Rizier123 Nothing yet, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to convert your string to valid time.

```
function getDuration($str){
    $result = array('h' => 0, 'm' => 0, 's' => 0);
    if(!preg_match('%^PT(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$%',$str, $matches)) return $result;

    if(isset($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[1])) $result['h'] = $matches[1];
    if(isset($matches[2]) && !empty($matches[2])) $result['m'] = $matches[2];
    if(isset($matches[3]) && !empty($matches[3])) $result['s'] = $matches[3];

    return $result;
}
```

**Result:**

```
print_r(getDuration('PT1H50M20S'));

//Array
//(
//    [h] => 1
//    [m] => 50
//    [s] => 20
//)
```

Comment: I tried `%^PT(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(\d+)S$%`which works, for some videos. If a video is 3m long then the string will be "PT3M" which doesn't work, is there any way to fix this?
EDIT: I changed it to `^PT(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$` which seems to be working, is this the correct way?

Comment: Now you can use with confidence. ;)

Comment: @Muki do you check this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the late reply, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+)(?=h\b)|(\d+)(?=m\b)|(\d+)(?=s\b)
```

Try this.Grab `$1` as `h` ,`$2` as `m` and so on.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vF0kU2/10

```
$re = "/(\\d+)(?=h\\b)|(\\d+)(?=m\\b)|(\\d+)(?=s\\b)/m";
$str = "\$time = \"PT1H50M20S\"; (Video is 1h 50m 20s long)\n\$time = \"PT6M14S\"; (Video is 6m 14s long)\n\$time = \"PT11S\"; (Video is 11s long)\n";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, there are no matches on match[1-3], the re doesn't work for string such as "PT6M14S", see here: http://regex101.com/r/aZ5fJ5/1